# Required T - provided void on REST controller using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to implement a REST controller to complete a delete operation and getting a error on the REST controller.

My BirdService

```
public interface BirdService {

    Bird create(Bird bird);
    Collection<Bird> list();
    Bird get(Long id);
    Bird update(Bird bird);
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

By BirdServiceImpl

```
public class BirdServiceImpl implements BirdService {

    private final BirdRepository birdRepository;

    // Other CRUDS deleted

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.info("About to delete bird : {}", id);
        Bird bird = new Bird();
        if (birdRepository.existsById(id)) {
             birdRepository.deleteById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

And the REST controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity deleteKiwi(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
            .body(birdService.delete(id));
}
```

My IDE however is warning me about this:

[image]

I understand it means there is a wrong type somewhere, but void is the response type for the derived JPA delete method - so why am I getting this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `/delete/{id}` supposed to return? Why are you creating a body in the response? Those are the first questions to answer. Then, technically, you're setting `void` as the body on that response. Well, clearly `void` cannot be passed as a value/expression. You probably just meant to call `birdService.delete(id)` before the return statement, then construct an empty body.

Comment: `delete` returns `void`.  But you're trying to pass the return from `delete` into `body`.

Answer (score 1):

As the Dawood mentioned in the comments, you're trying to populate a response body with a method that returns `void`. I believe best practice is to execute the delete method, and return 200:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity deleteKiwi(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    birdService.delete(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation thank you. I should have thought of that.